# PHP load text file in html table

Tags: php

On my website I have a table with the following code:

```
<table width="100%" id="tabloadwar" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<?php

$subdirs = array_map('intval', scandir("/war"));
$max = max($subdirs);

for($i=1;$i<=max;$i++){ ?>
<tr>
<td width="15%"><?php echo $i; ?></td>
<td width="85%">
<?php $percorso = file("dir1/content.txt"); $line = file($percorso); echo $line?></td></tr>

<?php } ?>
</table>
```

Using the code above, I want to create a table that has as much rows as the count of directories in my server. By the way it is not working because I don't see anything inside my table. An example of a row is this

```
<tr>
<td width="15%">1</td> // i value
<td width="85%">Italy</td> //text on the 1st line of my *.txt file
</tr>
```

Also, instead of that `name` I must put the content of a file called `dir1/content.txt`. It is not working too because I still don't see anything. Any help?

Comment: '/war' ? Maybe you meant '/var' ? Does it exist at all?

Comment: no no the folder is called 'war'

Comment: What's the current output look like? Are you presented with any errors?

Comment: And where is the part, where you scan directory, or retrieve contents of `content.txt` file?

Comment: the ouput is an empty table

Comment: @DavidJashi I think here but I see that this code I wrote is uncorrect: <?php $percorso = file("dir1/content.txt"); $line = file($percorso); echo $line?>

Comment: Does `apache` user have suitable permissions?

Comment: Will get to that part later (instead of dir1 you should put absolute path), first we should find out, why array is not populated

Comment: I've put the entire path but I still see the empty table

Comment: When using the full path, what does `print_r(scandir('path/to/war'))` print out?

Comment: nothing :( I don't know why...

Comment: I would check the permissions and make sure you're able to access the directory.

Comment: but the code I wrote is correct? not looking at permissions for the moment

Comment: Yes and no.  I don't know your file structure.  If `war` is a directory that is in the same directory as your `.php` file, then you don't need `/war`, the path will just be `war`.  Also, I don't know what you're trying to accomplish with the line that has the two `file` functions, but `file` returns an array of file contents.  Each item in that array is a line in the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must muse `$max` instead of `max` here `for($i=1;$i<=max;$i++){`

Try this code and see what happens..

```
<?php
  if ( !file_exists( "/war" ) ) {
    echo "'/war' not exists<br />";
  }
  if ( !file_exists( "dir1/content.txt" ) ) {
    echo "'content.txt' not exists<br />";
  }
?>
<table width="100%" id="tabloadwar" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<?php
  $subdirs  = array_map( "intval", scandir( "/war" ) );
  $max  = max( $subdirs );

  for( $i = 1; $i <= $max; $i++ ) {
?>
  <tr>
    <td width="15%"><?php echo $i; ?></td>
    <td width="85%">
    <?php
      $lines  = file( "dir1/content.txt" );
      echo implode( "<br />", $lines );
    ?>
    </td>
  </tr>

<?php
  }
?>
</table>
```

You said `....rows as the count of directories in my server...`
if you want to get the count of sub folders in folder you can use `glob` with `GLOB_ONLYDIR` flag

```
<?php
  $dirs = glob( "path/to/dir/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR );
  $total_dirs = count( $dirs );
?>
```